# SSLContext object is not gettng created to call third party api due to kafka consumer code

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I have an api which contains the Springboot kafka consumer code to consume the message from kafka topic automatically. after consuming messages it calls the upstream apis which contains https in url.

so calling the upstream api I need SSLConext object but when my api is trying to create SSLContext object giving below given error:

> java.security.KeyStoreException: problem accessing trust storejava.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
> at sun.security.ssl.TrustManagerFactoryImpl.engineInit(TrustManagerFactoryImpl.java:74)
> at javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory.init(TrustManagerFactory.java:250)
> at org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContextBuilder.loadTrustMaterial(SSLContextBuilder.java:109)
> at com.rbc.fraud.fid.listener.AutoActionConsumerListener.getHttpClientInstance(AutoActionConsumerListener.java:157)
> at com.rbc.fraud.fid.listener.AutoActionConsumerListener.consumeAutoActionServiceMsg(AutoActionConsumerListener.java:87)

I am using Restemplate to call upstream api.
I am using correct keystore file and password still it is giving error.

Note: When I am commenting the kafka Consumer code it is working fine and creating SSLContext Object as well as able to call upstream apis successfully.

I am using Springboot ConsumerFactory,ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory,@KafkaListener for consuming message from kafka topic.
Also implemented kerberos authentication in my code.

Kafka consumer code is working fine and consuming the messages. it is giving error when I am trying to create SSLConext Object to call upstream api.

I got stuck on this point and didn't get any solution for this.

Comment: are you initializing ConsumerFactory setting ssl.truststore.password variable ?

Comment: yes i am using System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", trustStorePassword);

Comment: and are you initializing RestTemplate ? Can you add the both configurations ?

Comment: SSLContext sslContext = SSLContextBuilder.create().loadKeyMaterial(new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("keystoreFileName.jks").getFile()),
"keyStorePassword".toCharArray(), "KeystorePassword".toCharArray()).loadTrustMaterial(acceptingTrustStrategy).useProtocol("TLS").build(); 
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().setSSLContext(sslContext)
.setSSLHostnameVerifier(new NoopHostnameVerifier()).build();

Comment: HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory rf = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
   RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(rf);
   sslContextObjectCreationStatus=sslContextObjectCreationStatus+"RestTemplate Object Status: "+ restTemplate;
   ResponseEntity<String> fmAlertRespEntity = restTemplate.exchange("url",HttpMethod.POST, new HttpEntity<>(object), String.class);

Comment: this is for restemplate

Comment: Now adding kafka configuration:

Comment: configProperties.put("retries", 0);
   configProperties.put("security.protocol", kafkaAuthentication);
   configProperties.put("client.id", clientId);
   configProperties.put("application.id", applicationId);
   configProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaServer);
   configProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);

Comment: configProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
     org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer.class);

   configProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
     io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer.class);

   configProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ErrorHandlingDeserializer.class);
   configProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ErrorHandlingDeserializer.class);configProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "latest");

Comment: configProperties.put("schema.registry.url", schemaRegistry); 

   configProperties.put("ssl.truststore.location", trustStorePath);
   System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", loginConfigPath);
   System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf", krb5ConfPath);
   System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", trustStorePassword);
      return configProperties;

Comment: I suggest you to edit your request (and hide the pwds) adding this code, so it will be readable

Comment: I just noticed one thing when I am commenting only below given code in kafkaconf file

Comment: System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", trustStorePassword); then it is creating sslcontext but not asgining any partitions to kafka and not consuming messages